# How to bring icon and text div side by side for medium device responsive design?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, grid

I was looking for this kind design for footer to be done during my responsive coding.
[Expected Design for footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0tQN.png)

But I was getting issue for bringing icon and text of **contact** part. The icon and relevant text are moving down. This is happening for Medium device (769px-992px). I tried to change different grid system for making responsive with col-md-x(X is number of grid that i want).[Image of displaced footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQYBT.png)

The footer code is added here. The contact section is named with "**footer-contact-item"**-`

```
<footer class="footer-area">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
               <!-- footer-About-item -->
               <div class="col-md-4 footer-About-item">
                  <h1>About cab Hub</h1>
                  <div class="footer-item-hr"></div>
                  <p>Quisque sollicitudin feugiat risus, eu posuere ex euismod eu. Phasellus hendrerit, massa efficitur.Quisque sollicitudin feugiat risus, eu posuere ex euismod eu.</p>
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
               <!-- footer-download-item -->
               <div class="col-md-4 footer-download-item">
                  <h1>Download</h1>
                  <div class="footer-item-hr"></div>
                  <p>Quisque sollicitudin feugiat risus, eu posuere ex euismod eu. Phasellus hendrerit,</p>
                  <div class="row mt-4">
                     <div class="col-md-6 col-8 col-sm-4">
                        <h3>Android Users</h3>
                        <h4>IOS Users</h4>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-6 col-4 col-sm-8">
                        <ul>
                           <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-android"></i></a></li>
                           <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-apple"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-4 footer-contact-item">
                  <h1>Contact</h1>
                  <div class="footer-item-hr"></div>
                  <!-- footer-contact-list -->
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-1 col-2 col-sm-1">
                        <h5><i class="fa  fa-map-marker"></i></h5>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-11 col-10 col-sm-11">
                        <h6>+123, Main Street, Your City, New York, USA 789456</h6>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- footer-contact-list -->
                  <div class="row mt-2">
                     <div class="col-md-1 col-2 col-sm-1">
                        <h5><i class="fa  fa-mobile"></i></h5>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-11 col-10 col-sm-11">
                        <h6>+123 4567 8900</h6>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- footer-contact-list -->
                  <div class="row mt-2">
                     <div class="col-md-1 col-2 col-sm-1">
                        <h5><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></h5>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-11 col-10 col-sm-11">
                        <h6>free@psdfreebies.com</h6>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- footer-contact-list -->
                  <div class="row mt-2">
                     <div class="col-md-1 col-2 col-sm-1">
                        <h5><i class="fa fa-mouse-pointer"></i></h5>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-11 col-10 col-sm-11">
                        <h6>www.psdfreebies.com</h6>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="copy-right text-center">
            <h3>Copyright © 2015 PSDfreebies.com</h3>
         </div>
      </footer>
```

`

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: Yes, I am using bootstrap.

Comment: Provide your external css file since it contains many styles and It becomes easier to help.